# Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in .htaccess doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, cors

I can't figure out why my `.htaccess` header settings doesn't work.

My `.htaccess` file content:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But when I remove `Header`'s and add them in `index.php` then everything works fine.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 137):

This should work:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: Don't forget to activate the apache module headers `a2enmod headers`

Comment: It fixed: "Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods"

Comment: Also, it's best to use `Header set` in this case. If the code is changed and it DOES set the header, having Apache do a `header add` will send out double ** headers. This will break clients like Restangular for example.

Comment: Don't forget, if needed, `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"`

Answer (score 25):

Just for the record, I was running into the exact same problem and none of the answers worked.

I used a headers checker tool: http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php

I was testing with my IP (`http://192.0.2.1/upload`) and what came back was the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently => 
Date => Sat, 10 Jan 2015 04:03:35 GMT
Server => Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
Location => http://192.0.2.1/upload/
Content-Length => 380
Connection => close
Content-Type => text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

There was a redirection happening and the AJAX request does not honor/follow redirects.

**It turned out to be the missing slash at the end of the domain** (http://192.0.2.1/upload**/**)

I tested again with slash at the end and I got this below. Added a slash in the script too, and it was now working.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK => 
Date => Sat, 10 Jan 2015 04:03:53 GMT
Server => Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0e PHP/5.3.8 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
X-Powered-By => PHP/5.3.8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin => *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods => PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers => *
Content-Length => 1435
Connection => close
Content-Type => text/html
```

Use this tool to test if your headers are good and to troubleshoot what is happening.

Comment: I have 11 tabs open right now trying to solve this. This answer should be in more places.

Comment: With mine, I needed to remove the trailing slash. So glad I found this. Spent so much time troubleshooting this when I new it should have been working hours ago.

Comment: have my uptick for the headers tool, even if this didnt solve it for me

Comment: I just want to thank you for the headers checker tool, really helped solve my issue

Answer (score 11):

I have a shared hosting on GoDaddy. I needed an answer to this question, too, and after searching around I found that it is possible.

I wrote an .htaccess file, put it in the same folder as my action page. Here are the contents of the .htaccess file:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Here is my ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.mydomain.com/myactionpagefolder/gbactionpage.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        beforeSend: beforeSendHandler,
        success: completeHandler,
        error: errorHandler,
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

See this article for reference:

[Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in .htaccess doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640596/header-set-access-control-allow-origin-in-htaccess-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 9):

Be careful on:

```
 Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

This is not judicious at all to grant access to everybody. It's preferable to allow a list of know trusted host only...

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://aaa.example"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://bbb.example"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://ccc.example"
```

Regards,

Comment: This won't work. Access-Control-Allow-Origin isn't allowed multiple values. You need to dynamically set the header based on the value of the Origin request header.

Answer (score 7):

I activated the Apache module headers a2enmod headers, and the issue has been solved.

Comment: Errors in the log weren't clear as to why the changes I was making would fail and this answer helped a great deal. `sudo a2enmod headers` and a restart got it working!

Answer (score 6):

Try this in the .htaccess of the external root folder

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Be careful with doing `Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` This is not judicious at all to grant access to everybody. I think you should user:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4):

I +1'd Miro's answer for the link to the header-checker site http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php. It pops up an obnoxious ad every time you use it, but it is, nevertheless, very useful for verifying the presence of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

I'm reading a .json file from the javascript on my web page. I found that adding the following to my .htaccess file fixed the problem when viewing my web page in IE 11 (version 11.447.14393.0):

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I also added the following to /etc/httpd.conf (Apache's configuration file):

```
AllowOverride All
```

The header-checker site verified that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is now being sent (thanks, Miro!).

However, Firefox 50.0.2, Opera 41.0.2353.69, and Edge 38.14393.0.0 all fetch the file anyhow, even **without** the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. (Note: they might be checking IP addresses, since the two domains I was using are both hosted on the same server, at the same IPv4 address.)

However, Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit) ignores the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and fails anyhow, erroneously reporting:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin '*{mydomain}*' is therefore not allowed access.

I think this has got to be some sort of "first." IE is working correctly; Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Edge are all buggy; and Chrome is the **worst**. Isn't that the exact opposite of the usual case?

Answer (score 1):

To complete the most upvoted answer, I want to add the case whenever the options to the header is not add in a response request, you could add the **always** keyword from Apache.

In my case i needed to add the access control allow origin in the response of the redirection and not in the result of the redirection.

And a redirection is giving the 302 code status so the header wasn't filled with the correct information.

In this case I needed to add it :

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

For more information you can check this thread :
[Apache: difference between "Header always set" and "Header set"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39502968/apache-difference-between-header-always-set-and-header-set)

Answer (score 0):

After spending half a day with nothing working. 
Using a header check service though everything was working.
The firewall at work was stripping them

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "your domain"
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With"
</IfModule>
```

It's preferable to allow a list of know trusted host.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is trying this, the most upvoted answer should work.  However, if you are having issues it could be possible the browser has cached the REQUEST. To confirm append a query string.