# htaccess Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: .htaccess, cors, cross-domain

I'm creating a script that loads externally on other sites. It loads CSS and HTML and works fine on my own servers.

However, when I try it on another website it displays this awful error:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Here you can see it loads perfectly: http://tzook.info/bot/

But on this other website it shows the error:
http://cantloseweight.co/robot/

I uploaded the loading script to jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TL5LK/

I tried editing the htaccess  file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>    
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
</IfModule>
```

Or like this:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Try this in the .htaccess of the external root folder :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

And if it only concerns .js scripts you should wrap the above code inside this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
...
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: if we match files by adding the filesmatch block, then what does the `*` do?

Comment: And do I need to restart the server after doing this? I apply the code above but it still won't let me access \.json, I changed `js` to `json`.

Comment: @shenkwen The `*` allows any origin domain to access this resource. It's not a list of resources, but a list of referencing domains.

Comment: In case it doesn't work, you should try enabling the `headers` module: `a2enmod headers`

Comment: For completeness, to anyone that is using `access-control-allow-origin` dynamically (changing the URL value based on the requesting origin) instead of `*`, you must also include the header `Vary: Origin`. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-http-caches

Comment: How this will work when there are GET parameters after `?`?

Answer (score 81):

no one says that you also have to have **mod_headers** enabled, so if still not working, try this:

(following tips works on Ubuntu, don't know about other distributions)

you can check list of loaded modules with

```
apache2ctl -M
```

to enable mod_headers you can use

```
a2enmod headers
```

of course after any changes in Apache you have to restart it:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Then you can use

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

And if mod_headers is not active, this line will do nothing at all. You can try skip if clause and just add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` in your config, then it should throw error during start if mod_headers is not active.

Comment: been trying all the options I could find on Google and, as you said, no one said anything about mod_headers. Thank!

Comment: My mod_headers are active and added this line in .htaccess(same place as mentioned), but still am getting this error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400..Pls suggest!

Comment: mod_headers was the missing thing! This is working perfectly with .htaccess rule. Thank you.

Comment: @SachinS a 400 error is not found, 500 is server error. Start there.

Answer (score 40):

from my experience;

if it doesn't work from within `php` do this in `.htaccess` it worked for me

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin http://www.vknyvz.com  
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
</IfModule>
```

- credentials can be true or false depending on your ajax request params

Comment: This didn't work for me but I was able to get it working in php, same principle.

Answer (score 26):

Add an `.htaccess` file with the following directives to your fonts folder, if have problems accessing your fonts. Can easily be modified for use with **.css** or **.js** files.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: It should be noted that the above `<FilesMatch>` directive is unnecessary, _if_, as suggested above, your `.htaccess` file is in your fonts directory _and_ your fonts directory _only_ contains `.eot`, .`ttf`, `.otf` and/or `.woff` files.

Answer (score 11):

In Zend Framework 2.0 i had this problem. Can be solved in two way .htaccess or php header i prefer .htaccess so i modified .htaccess from:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

to

```
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

and it start to work

Comment: This saved my day, php couddnt work, so htaccess did it.

Answer (score 10):

The other answers didn't work for me, this is what ended up doing the trick for apache2:

1) Enable the headers mod:

`sudo a2enmod headers`

2) Create the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/headers.conf` file and insert:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

3) Restart your server:

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on my Ubuntu 16.10 server.

Comment: This worked also for me. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 server. Thank you.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04. Firefox 70.0.1 wasn't happy with just the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, though, and I had to add the Access-Control-Allow-Methods one as well.

Comment: @songololo I could not locate this file for apache in Centos 7. I looked everywhere in the /etc/httpd directory. Can you please let me know how can I implement it on Centos?

Comment: @Mainuddin, sorry, I'm not familiar with Centos. Hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: Hi! if the .htaccess answers don't work for you, but this one does, then you probably have to enable .htaccess by setting `AllowOverride All` in your server config file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf)

Answer (score 9):

BTW: the .htaccess config must be done on the server hosting the API. For example you create an AngularJS app on x.com domain and create a Rest API on y.com, you should set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in the .htaccess file on the root folder of y.com not x.com :)

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Also as Lukas mentioned make sure you have enabled mod_headers if you use Apache

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you don't have a redirect happening. This can happen if you don't include the trailing slash in the URL.

See this answer for more detail – https://stackoverflow.com/a/27872891/614524

Answer (score 0):

If your host not at pvn or dedicated, it's dificult to restart server.

Better solution from me, just edit your CSS file (at another domain or your subdomain) that call font eot, woff etc to your origin (your-domain or www yourdomain). it will solve your problem.

I mean, edit relative url on css to absolute url origin domain