# Ajax responce error : Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I am using ajax in one of my magento project, every thing is working fine with http://url.com but when i use https://url.com it response nothing and show below error.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://url.com. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Use Access-Control-Allow-Origin in your header.

Comment: could you please elaborate how can i use this into my header.

Comment: I think you can add in .htaaccess like <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule> .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin/13871027#13871027

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, hope this is the solution. You have to access AJAX request on the same url of the request page:

```
http://url.com -> http://url.com  
http://www.url.com -> http://www.url.com  
https://url.com -> https://url.com
```

Comment: This works for me, but i want to hit ajax from http:// to https://. Is this possible?

Comment: No, cause it considers `https://` another domain, different from `http://`, there are few server-side plugins to allow Cross-Origins requests but I know nothing about them. Sorry.