# .htaccess file Not Being Read

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos

My .htaccess file is not being read, I have put a .htaccess file in /var/www/html which contains

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

And then my http.conf file looks like this

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
<Directory />
AllowOverride none
Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
AllowOverride None
# Allow open access:
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And the file I want to access in is in my /var/www/html folder but when I try to access it form another sever I keep getting this error

```
Image from origin 'http://serverB' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Why isn't my .htacces being read and how can I make it be read?

Thanks

Comment: `ls -l` will show permissions on files, maybe there will be a clue.

Comment: @ESYSCODER this listed the permissions of files in my root directory Im not sure how that helps?

Comment: I was thinking you will add results of it to the answer. Are permission on .htaccess allowing apache to read it? User/group match apache process user/group?

Comment: @ESYSCODER my .htaccess file is at `/var/www/html` not in `/root` and the owner and group of the `.htaccess` file is unknown do you I need to set that to apache?

Comment: Apache has to be able to read it, in `/var/www/html` do `chmod 0644 .htaccess` to allow everyone to read it or change user to apache user.

Comment: I set the Permission on .htaccess to 0666 and still it is not being read

Comment: @ESYSCODER I changed 0644 but i dont think it is being read

Comment: how do you requesting image from another server: ajax, curl ? show details of request

Comment: What happens if you add a new line `ThisShouldCrash` to your .htaccess?

Comment: Are you trying to access a font file? Is the headers module enabled in httpd? Pasting the full request path/response you're getting from server will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow the `AllowOverride All` in the `/html` file as well, Im not sure why but I had the same problem also make sure to restart the apache after you save the `.htaccess` file otherwise the changes will not apply.

Also make sure that you do not have any other `.htaccess` files anywhere else as using `add` could add the headers extra time cause error.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to the `.htaccess` file.

I was facing the same issue whenever I use reverse proxy since it was my dev machine I just add these lines into the `.htaccess` file and it solved this issue.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is mod_headers enabled on the server? check with this command:

```
apache2ctl -M
```

If not, enable it using this command:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

After that restart the apache server.

If it still does not work checkout the following answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13871027/2507790

Comment: I got `-bash: apache2ctl: command not found` when running the first command and `sudo: a2enmod: command not found` when running the second command

Comment: use this for centos: httpd -M

Comment: when I do that I got a long list of moduels

Comment: Checkout this answer for a better understanding of apache modules on centos: http://serverfault.com/a/56435/325169 . And just to make sure that htaccess is being read by the server, try something else, maybe a redirect from the htaccess file