# How to bypass Cross origin policy

Tags: javascript, php, same-origin-policy

Mobile app where it needs to get access to a JSON file in another server. And its showing cross origin policy blocked. So is there any way to bypass or have the access to the file ?

Comment: Do you have access to the other server?

Comment: CORS is there for a reason. So unless you have access to the target server to change the CORS policy, you will not be able to circumvent it.

Comment: Try searching for [cross origin JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+origin+JSON)

Comment: yes i have the access to the other server but we cannot use any php code in the main app

Comment: Then simply apply the cross domain header.. but this would require php still or to use a htaccess file to apply the header

Comment: I've edited my answer and included a link for using a htaccess file, this should help in your case.. Have a read of the page first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already answered, you want a simple php proxy script.

This way your server grabs the json file and you simply access your server from client side. . That way javascript is only dealing with the same domain.

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/data.json');
?>
```

**Proxy.php**

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/'.$_REQUEST['file']);
?>
```

Another way also would be to send all of the request headers as a query string, this could be post/get as well

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
    $sQuery = http_build_query($_REQUEST);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo file_get_contents('https://www.example.com?'.$sQuery);
    exit;
}

?>
```

Using the second example you can try something like `http://localhost/proxy.php?file=somefile.json`

**HTACCESS METHOD**

Refer the following page about using a htaccess file on the server [htaccess Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin)

```
<FilesMatch ".(json|js|jsn)">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: As its for mobile app which will be for windows phone and firfox os and which only supports html,css and JS we cannot use any php in the main file which will be containing in the app. So any related solution to this ?

Comment: True.. my mistake, corrected.

Comment: Your server where you host the app should have php, if your app uses only local files then you will need to host a php file to do this trick with a server or change the cross domain header on the server hosting the json file

Comment: You too!  You got taken by the PHP tag.  Why would someone tag a question with PHP if a PHP solution is not an option??  BTW, I really like your solution. Very simple proxy. If nothing else I'm sure you have helped others.  This OP?, not so sure that is possible.

Comment: This is the simplest it can ever be for a PHP proxy, but agreed as it will help others. Though in this case he can use a HTACCESS file on the other server and allow cross domain for the set file(s)

Answer (score 1):

You categorized this under PHP.  You would do well to get the JSON with PHP then use PHP to create the data required by the JS.

Without more information regarding your app, I am very limited here.

This is a very typical PHP example geting json data into JavaScript:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/data.jsn'),true);
$JS = 'var data = ';
foreach ($json as $key => $value){
  $JS .= "[$key,$value],"
}
$JS = substr($JS,0,-1) . ';';  // remove trailing comma, add semicolon



echo <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
$JS
//]]>
</script>
EOT;
```

Comment: there is a happy medium in which PHP proxies the existing request for JSON and just passes it through. No need to blend PHP and JS, nor to change anything other than a URL in the existing code.

Comment: @JAAulde  Is "just passes it through" not what I did?  The only other way I can see PHP being the proxy to JS  would be to use AJAX, and that is too slow and requires an additional HTTP request by the Browser.  I have found over the years that blending PHP and JS  to have tremendous benefits.  Simple, efficient, and quick, I like all three.  Whether oit can be used here, I do not know, not enough info.

Comment: I infer that the OP is already using AJAX (though I could be wrong), and it may be something which continuously reloads data during the lifecycle of the app. Server side proxy is standard implementation in situations like this if CORS cannot be implemented. I will also note that the manual creation of JS data as you are doing in building out the `$JS` string should be avoided and use of JSON serialization should replace it. The former is error prone and much harder to read. In this case the data is already JSON, so it's extra work too.

Comment: I would have to agree with you, the OP is very likely using AJAX.  If the case were that multiple AJAX calls were being made or the AJAX call being made is altered by user interaction, then my solution falls apart quickly.  I still like to spread the word about blending PHP and JS.  When it's needed it's great. I have never seen any code that does it like I do.  I use this technique a lot.  Not necessarily for JSON but getting db data into JS.

Comment: As its for mobile app which will be for windows phone and firfox os and which only supports html,css and JS we cannot use any php in the main file which will be containing in the app. So any related solution to this ?

Comment: Well!  Thanks for the down vote for my efforts! Then you may want to remove the PHP tag from your Question.  I did preface my answer with a comment about the PHP tag being questionable, and that my answer my not apply because your question left too many unanswered questions.  While sometimes I can read minds, it requires the person to have one.

Comment: You had an upvote from me as your approach was right before we found out they can not use PHP

Comment: You got my upvote.  Your solution is perfect for the cases where mine is not.

Comment: Rather than edit in a banner, either delete your answer or just leave your post up for others to vote on. The OP is not the only person you may be helping here.

Answer (score 1):

Use header function. check out this link [how to bypass Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564832/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin)

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: this answer needs some background info and further explaining.

Comment: This would only work if you have access to the other server..

Comment: I don't see any reason why their is a negative vote, nor do I see any reason for explaining a simple function. The question was how to bypass  the problem and I gave the solution. If you are capable of building a Mobile app, write a Json and PHP code, I am sure you are capable of finding a simple header function without much effort.

Comment: @Sam it's not you.  It's them.  You try to help, and sometimes your efforts are not understood, they are misunderstood.  The OP down voted me also.  As you see this question should not have had a PHP tag.  So it is your fault the OP is not very savvy.  And not trying to be racist.

Comment: Actually people downvote something like this because its only worthy of a comment.. Its not a complete answer.. And further more if they require a non PHP method then it does not help their further.. Expand your answer beyond one line / a comment amount of text.

Comment: I do not encourage spoon-feeding neither should anyone in stackflow community.  It only indicates lazyness on behalf of the OP, something we surely discourage.

Comment: Sam... simply learn what is a answer worthy content vs a comment worthy content.... thats all i am going to say on this,.

Comment: @Mayhem: click on the link to my answer. 111 vote for one line answer to a similar question. its not about line, Mayhem. This question does not require 100 line of answer.

Comment: First off... You edited it..Your first response was just the single php line... Second the link still on refers to a source page that that still only covers PHP... Which has been established as not usable in this case. Once again, you need to put more effort into your answer.. Either way show some actual effort or explain things.. Dont just post raw answers.

Comment: I edited because someone wanted me to spoon-feed. I understood the question, my answer was relevant, OP up voted me and I am pretty sure you still haven't understood the question. This is a php question. The server side is PHP and the questioner has access to PHP server as he clearly stated. but does not want to use PHP in main app which is client side. It is generally a hybrid mobile app scenario where using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header opens a door for cross-origin access by specific requesting origins. Hope I made it clear.