# Unable to get data from json file on local server (port: 3000)

Tags: html, json, http

I am hosting an html page on localhost:8888 with a MAMP Server and I am trying to get some data from a JSON file which I am hosting on localhost:3000 on the 'categories' route. Firstly, I wanted to know is this possible ?
If it is not possible, is it possible for me to route the JSON data to another site. If it is possible, here is the script I have embedded in my HTML

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         setInterval(test,500);
         console.log("document ready");
         alert('page ready');
      });
      function test() {
         $.ajax({
           url:"HTTP://localhost:3000/categories",
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           success: function(json){
            $("#Address1").html(json[0]["id"]);;

           }
        });
     }
   </script>
```

Here is the JSON file :

```
[{"_id":"5624711f1a530785d511e747","__v":0,"name":"Beverages","description":"Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales","created":"2015-10-19T04:27:11.649Z"}]
```

Currently, It doesn't display any data. I have tried pure JS instead of jquery but it doesn't help.

This is what I got in the Chrome Console :  GET localhost:3000/categories?callback=jQuery1113012827125121839345_1445236000644&_=‌​1445236000645 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Added http:// - does not make a difference

Comment: Make sure your domain `localhost:3000/categories` is working ??

Comment: `JSONP` is meant for that. You can pass your `callback` in the url

Comment: You have valid JSON, so next step as suggested is that your server is actually working. If you visit http://localhost:3000/categories does it show your data?? If not, you have a server side issue that needs resolving. You can route the JSON `from` another server using a proxy script.. a PHP example would be using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997705/how-to-bypass-cross-origin-policy/29998032#29998032 as you will see my answer in there

Comment: It is working, but unfortunately the data on port 8888 does not display. Is my code alright though ?

Comment: Try using the proxy script i supplied, while i have never really bothered using ajax across ports... Some how i get the feeling it will be a cross origin error.. Use the console in your browser, goto the network tab and look at the response for the ajax call.. It will give you a 200,404,500 or similar code.

Comment: As in the proxy script would be hosted on port 8888, and it does a post/get/request to port 3000..

Comment: I checked the console in chrome and got this error :   GET localhost:3000/categories?callback=jQuery1113012827125121839345_1445236000644&_=1445236000645 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: @Shashank: Do you need to mention the protocol http:// in the url?

Comment: @MohamedHussain Hi ! I just tired that ... does not make a difference

Comment: @Shashank Please check this link https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/ and also as you are using jsonp, you need to mention the callback in the server localhost:8888

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery