# how to change logo within an iframe depending on top URL of the window

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am trying to solve this problem since morning now. I want the an image file (logo) with an iframe to change depending on certain URLs. That is when the iframe is embedded inside a specific domain there is an internal logo and when it is embedded outside of the domain there is logo external. But I keep on getting this error **SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a frame with origin Protocols, domains, and ports must match.** I dont know how can I work around this? Is there an alternative way to do this?

here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  var currentUrl = window.parent.location.hostname;
  if (currentUrl == 'www.mysite.com' || currentUrl == 'www.specific.com') {
    $(function() {
        $('img').remove('.logo-external');
    });
} else {
  $(function() {
        $('img').remove('.logo-internal');
    });
}
});

<div class="footer-right">
        <a class="logo" href="" target="_blank">
            <img class='logo-external' src="{{ ASSET_PATH }}logo-external.jpg" height="18" />
            <img class='logo-internal' src="{{ ASSET_PATH }}logo.png" height="18" />
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: `<iframe src="foo.html?src=internal">` and then test for that `src` query var?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your answer correctly. But I do not want to change <iframe> attribute. Since this is for an app that will export iframes which will then be embedded by users into their websites. So my only option is to change it from the template it self.

Comment: You can't use `window.parent` unless the iframe and its parent are on the same domain, or if [the parent domain allows the child one to access it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin). That is only feasible if you have control over the parent server. @MarcB gave a workaround you can use, to _flag_ any internal request, but that requires you to have a different iframe URL than your other clients.

Comment: is there an alternative method  to window.parent to achieve this result?

Comment: Yes, see my answer and try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `window.parent` unless the iframe and its parent are on the same domain, or if [the parent domain allows the child one to access it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin). That is only feasible if you have control over the parent server. However, there is a workaround:

Replace

```
var currentUrl = window.parent.location.hostname;
```

with

```
var temp = document.createElement("a");
temp.href = document.referrer;
var currentUrl = temp.hostname;
```

[JS Fiddle demo using `window.parent` (not working)](http://jsfiddle.net/sfcruhko/)

[JS Fiddle demo using `document.referrer` (does work)](http://jsfiddle.net/oreojqpb/)