# No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested resource .htaccess

Tags: javascript, python, linux, .htaccess

I am trying to send a post Request from `www.websiteA.com` to `www.websiteB.com`. I am sending the POST from  Javascript with `XMLHttpRequest` on A to a python script on B. The python file on B, is called `my_save.py` and is located at `/var/www/cgi-bin/my_save.py`and so in the directory `/var/www/` I added a `.htaccess` file that contained this

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

As I saw on this question [htaccess Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin) and other places telling me to do this.

But the same error

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://websiteB.com/cgi-bin/my_save.py. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://websiteA.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

How can get rid of this error and make the post to websiteB?

Thanks for the help

Comment: have you read [CORS documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) - not the definitive CORS docs, but I find them readable

Comment: Are you sure `mod_headers` is enabled? Remove the condition statement `<IfModule mod_headers.c>` and just leave `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` If you get a server error it's probably not enabled otherwise it is enabled if you don't get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may instead just add this to the top of your python file:

```
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

Source: [Here](http://enable-cors.org/server_cgi.html)