# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '…' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: .htaccess, web, unity-game-engine

I am trying to publish a unity based game(WebGL) to a free hosting site. I am getting this error while opening the .html game file on firefox too (on Chrome also but chrome doesn't support unity now)

```
        XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://parked-domain.org/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
 header is present on the requested resource. 
    Origin 'http://shantanusingh.byethost7.com' is therefore not allowed access.
        UnityLoader.js:1 Invoking error handler due to
        Uncaught unknown compression method

UnityLoader.js:1 Uncaught unknown compression method
UnityLoader.js:1 Invoking error handler due to
Uncaught incorrect header check

UnityLoader.js:1 Uncaught incorrect header check

UnityLoader.js:1 Invoking error handler due to
Uncaught incorrect header check

UnityLoader.js:1 Uncaught incorrect header check
```

Its a very simple game with no database access, no php stuff.

I've tried deleting the .htaccess file , adding additional code in .htaccess file as stated in this discussion http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/uncaught-exception-unknown-compression-method.373302/ but the problem remains as it is.

**I want to know if it is possible to load unity game on a free hosting site ? If yes then how to tackle this problem ?**

Comment: I think you need to concentrate on the first line of your error log - google Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Also, if you can not afford a paid hosting for testing I would advise to set one up on your own machine because free hosting servers are usually very very limited in functionality. (like throwing Access-Control-Allow-Origin at you)

Comment: This is about CORS,did you search at all for the error message. That is a pretty common issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin