# How to solve 'Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on an app using `Vue js`.
According to my setting I  need to pass to a variable to my URL when setting change.

```js
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    $.get('http://172.16.1.157:8002/firstcolumn/' + c1v + '/' + c1b, function (data) { 
      // some code...
    });
```

But when my app hit on URL, it shows the following message.

```
Failed to load http://172.16.1.157:8002/firstcolumn/2017-03-01/2017-10-26: Redirect from 'http://172.16.1.157:8002/firstcolumn/2017-03-01/2017-10-26' to 'http://172.16.1.157:8002/firstcolumn/2017-03-01/2017-10-26/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: The issue is because the Same Origin Policy is preventing the response from being received due to the originating/receiving domains being different due to the port numbers. To fix this you'll need to return CORS headers in the response from `http://172.16.1.157:8002/firstcolumn/...`. Exactly how you do that will depend on what server side infrastructure you're using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: In this case, Origin A does GET request to Origin B ; the response redirects to a different location in Origin B. The solution is to trick Chrome into thinking Origin B is Origin A. What if Origin B redirected to Origin C; can we direct to any Origin C, or must we trick Origin C  to appear as Origin A? I think we **can** redirect to any Origin C (for example redirect  to a third party single-signon page, or to www.stackoverflow.com ) , regardless of Origin A or  the Origin C's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header)

Comment: In my case, none of the answers worked, and at the end it turned out to be an error on my middleware  ( in local server).  In case it helps someone

Answer (score 108, accepted):

In addition to what awd mentioned about getting the person responsible for the server to reconfigure (an impractical solution for local development) I use a change-origin chrome plugin like this:

1. <strike>[Moesif Orign & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc)</strike> (use to be free but now wants a work email address >_>)
2. [Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) (tested in 2023)

You can make your `local dev server (ex: localhost:8080)` to appear to be coming from `172.16.1.157:8002 or any other domain`.

> *In case the 2nd plugin link breaks in the future or the plugin writer decides to capitalize off the fame of this thread, open your browser's
> plugin marketplace and search "allow cors", there's going to be a
> bunch of them.*

Comment: Im not sure how to set it up, can you explain further? Screenshots would be nice.

Comment: @altShiftDev Does this plugin have any options to handle: "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."?

Comment: Try to put your real ip instead of the localhost. Try to google your ip and replace 'localhost' with that @Black

Comment: A word of warning: the Moesif Origin & CORS Changer plug-in requires you enter a work-related e-mail address to access the advanced settings. I would not recommend.

Answer (score 49):

Thanks all, I solved by this extension on chrome.

[Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

Comment: The link is now broken :(

Comment: broken link, no description at all.

Comment: Update the link my friend!

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

Comment: You don't need an Extension for Chrome: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60950835/2280067

Comment: the extension is just a temporary fix and not a solution to the problem

Comment: This is not a solution. Are you going to ask everyone to install a chrome extension?

Comment: This is an extension for Chrome

Comment: What if it still doesn't work? The plugin shows that CORS is allowed, but the client request is still blocked by CORS policy. What might be happening?

Comment: How does this extension work? Why does is work with this extension turned on? Is there any way to implement this method directly to my website? Unfotunately I do not have permission to change server settings.

Answer (score 26):

If you have control over your server, you can use PHP:

```
<?PHP
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```

Comment: better add to the .htaccess file, this would apply to the entire project and not just to the sites you have added this snippet.

Comment: may i know how to solve this from angular side?

Comment: for me it does not even reach php script

Comment: [.htaccess - htaccess Access-Control-Allow-Origin - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 20):

> I will assume that you're a front-end developer only and that you don't have access to the backend of the application (regarding the tags of the question).

Short answer on how to **properly** solve this in your case? You can't, you'll need somebody else.

---

#### What is this about?

You need to understand that CORS is a **security thing**, it's not just here to annoy you just for fun.
It's purpose is to mainly prevent the usage of a (malicious) HTTP call from a **non-whitelisted frontend** to your backend with some critical mutation.

You could give a look to this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/4KHiSt0oLJ0) or any other one really, but I recommend a visual video because text-based explanations can be quite hard to understand.

You also need to understand that if you use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or any other tool to try your API call, you will **not** get the CORS issue. The reason being that those tools are not Web frontends but rather some server-based tools.

Hence, don't be surprised if something is working there but not in your Vue app, the context is different.

---

#### Now, how to solve this?

1. Depending on the framework used by your backend team, the syntax may be quite different but overall, you'll need to tell them to provide something like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000` (or any other port you'll be using).

PS: Using `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` would be quite risky because it would allow anybody to access it, hence why a stricter rule is recommended.

2. If you're using a service, like an API to send SMS, payment, some Google console or something else really, you'll need to allow your `localhost` in the dashboard of the service. Ask for credentials to your manager or Tech Lead.
3. If you have access to the backend, you could it yourself as shown here (ExpressJS in this example): https://flaviocopes.com/cors/

---

#### How to hack it in a dirty way?

If you're in a damn hurry and want to get something really dirty, you could use a lot of various hacks a listed in the other answers, here's a quick list:

- use [any extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) who is able to create a middleware and forward the request to the backend (it will work because it's not directly coming from your frontend)
- force your browser to [disable CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102819/8816585), not sure how this would actually solve the issue
- use a proxy, if you're using Nuxt2, [@nuxtjs/proxy](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module) is a popular one but any kind of proxy (even a real backend will do the job)
- any other hack related somehow to the 3 listed above...

---

In the end, solving the CORS issue can be done quite fast and easily. You only need to communicate with your team or find something on your side (if you have access to the backend/admin dashboard of some service).

I strongly recommend trying to get it right from the beginning because it's related to security and that it may be forgotten down the road...

Answer (score 18):

**Using npm:**

To allow cross-origin requests install 'cors':

```
npm i cors
```

Add this in the server-side:

```
let cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: does not working

Answer (score 16):

Ask the person maintaining the server at http://172.16.1.157:8002/ to add your hostname to Access-Control-Allow-Origin hosts, the server should return a header similar to the following with the response-

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yourhostname:port
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it says origin is localhost, so cors get triggered. I think?

Answer (score 15):

When you have this problem with Chrome, you don't need an Extension.
Start Chrome from the Console:
*chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security*

Maybe you have to close all Tabs in Chrome and restart it.

Comment: Simple and perfect.  My full path was like this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Answer (score 14):

The approved answer to this question is not valid.

You need to set headers on your server-side code

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','Content-Type','Authorization');
    next(); 
})
```

You can also try a chrome extension to add these headers automatically.

Comment: I have these set in the header. I am still getting the CORS error.

Comment: You might need to name the policy and add [EnableCors(<policy name>)] to the server controller

Comment: The third `setHeader` call should set `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` instead of a duplicated `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`.

Answer (score 10):

Hello If I understood it right you are doing an [XMLHttpRequest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to do something different when you want to do a cross-domain request. A tutorial about how to achieve that is [Using CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

When you are using postman they are not restricted by this policy. Quoted from [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170129112212/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr):

**Regular web pages can use the XMLHttpRequest object to send and receive data from remote servers, but they're limited by the same origin policy. Extensions aren't so limited. An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions.**

Answer (score 9):

To add the CORS authorization to the header using Apache, simply add the following line inside either the `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>` or `<VirtualHost>` sections of your server config (usually located in a *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or apache.conf), or within a `.htaccess` file:

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

And then restart apache.

Altering headers requires the use of mod_headers. Mod_headers is enabled by default in Apache, however, you may want to ensure it's enabled.

Comment: added into my `.htaccess` of local project and works like charm, don't forget to reboot your server / mamp / apache, whatever you use.

Comment: [.htaccess - htaccess Access-Control-Allow-Origin - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in my Vue.js and SpringBoot projects. If somebody work with spring you can add this code:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {  
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();  
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();  
    config.setAllowCredentials(true); 
    // *** URL below needs to match the Vue client URL and port ***
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:8080")); 
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));  
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));  
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);  
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);  
    return bean;  
}
```

I found solution in this article [Build a Simple CRUD App with Spring Boot and Vue.js](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/11/20/build-crud-spring-and-vue)

Answer (score 4):

You are making a request to external domain `172.16.1.157:8002/` from your local development server that is why it is giving cross origin exception.
Either you have to allow headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` in both frontend and backend or alternatively use this extension [cors header toggle - chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/omcncfnpmcabckcddookmnajignpffnh?hl=en) unless you host backend and frontend on the same domain.

Comment: Hey, the chrome extension link provided is broken. Can you please update the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Try running this command in your terminal and then test it again.

```
curl -H "origin: originHost" -v "RequestedResource"
```

Eg:

If my `originHost` equals `https://localhost:8081/` and my `RequestedResource` equals `https://example.com/`

My command would be as below:

```
curl -H "origin: https://localhost:8081/" -v "https://example.com/"
```

If you can notice the following line then it should work for you.

**< access-control-allow-origin: ***

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Do specify `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")`
in Controller class.

Answer (score 4):

## Reason for Error

This is a cross origin request because the address from which the request is made (*in this case* `localhost:8080`) is different from the one of the requested resource (`172.16.1.157`), hence the CORS issue

The error in this case denotes that the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) is missing from the server's response.

This header is used by servers to denote which domains are allowed to request the resource that they are serving. All browsers throw an error when this header is absent during a cross origin request (*which is the case here*)

## Possible solutions

A. If you are in control of the server, you could modify the response headers that the server sends to meet your use case.

B. But looking closely, it seems like you are debugging this locally, in which case it would be easier to use a browser extension that does this for you.

I use [Requestly](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-open-source-htt/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa?hl=en) for debugging http related errors. This CORS issue can be solved by using their Header Rule.

Create a new Header Rule and configure it as such

1. Rule matching condition (where you want the rule to be applied): `URL` `Contains` `172.16.1.157`
2. Select `Response Headers`
3. Select `Override Response Headers`
4. Set the Request Header as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
5. Set the header value as either `*` (*to allow requests from all domains*) or `http://localhost:8080`

[image: Header Rule condition]

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this temporarily by using the Firefox add-on, [**CORS Everywhere**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/). Just open Firefox, press Ctrl+Shift+A , search the add-on and add it!

Comment: Thanks this helps to avoid all the hassle and test the code from localhost.

Answer (score 2):

You won't believe this,
**Make sure to add "." at the end of the "url"**

I got a similar error with this code:

```
fetch(https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson)
.then( response => {
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.results);
}).catch(error => console.log('Request failed:', error))
```

The error I got:

```
 Access to fetch at 'https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson'
 from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy:
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
 resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

But I realized after a lot of research that the problem was that I did not copy the 
right URL address from the iTunes API documentation.

**It should have been**

`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson.`

**not**

`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=jack+johnson`

> Notice the dot at the end

There is a huge explanation about why the dot is important quoting issues about DNS and character encoding but the truth is you probably do not care. Try adding the dot it might work for you too.

When I added the "." everything worked like a charm.

I hope it works for you too.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me, it broke the API call actually.

Answer (score 2):

install:

```
npm i cors
```

Then include cors():

```
app.get("/list",cors(),(req,res) =>{

});
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the Berke Kaan Cetinkaya's answer.
If you have control over your server, you can do the following in ExpressJs:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
// update to match the domain you will make the request from
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "YOUR-DOMAIN.TLD");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});
```

https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html

Answer (score 2):

I tried this code,and that works for me.You can see the documentation in this [link](https://socket.io/fr/docs/v3/handling-cors)

```
var io = require("socket.io")(http, {
cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
   }
 })
```

Comment: try this still getting error

Answer (score 1):

The reason that I came across this error was that I hadn't updated the path for different environments.

Comment: Our issue was folder permissions, even though we got this type of error. So it was a red herring for us.

Answer (score 0):

you have to customize security for your browser or allow permission through customizing security. (it is impractical for your local testing)
to know more about please go through the link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

These errors may be caused due to follow reasons, ensure the following steps are followed. To connect the local host with the local virtual machine(host). Here, I'am connecting http://localhost:3001/ to the http://abc.test Steps to be followed:

1.****We have to allow CORS, placing Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* in header of request
may not work. Install a google extension which enables a CORS request.****

2.Make sure the credentials you provide in the request are valid.

3.Make sure the vagrant has been provisioned. Try vagrant up --provision this make the localhost connect to db of the homestead.

4. Try changing the content type of the header. header:{ **'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;application/json'** }
   this point is very important.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem in a specific scenario :

If

1. AWS APIGW is your backend with authentication enabled and
2. authentication fails,

your browser may end up complaining about CORS even if CORS is enabled in APIGW. You also need to enable CORS for 4XX as follows

`API:YourAPI` > `Resources` > `/YourResource` > `Actions` > `Enable CORS` > `Gateway Responses for yourAPI` check `Default 4XX`

Authentication will still fail but it won't look like CORS is the root cause

Answer (score -12):

```
$.get('https://172.16.1.157:8002/firstcolumn/' + c1v + '/' + c1b, function (data) { 
  // some code...
});
```

Just put "https" .