# CORS blocking client request in Nuxt.js

Tags: vuejs2, cors, vuex, nuxt.js

I am having issues when making a client request.

I have followed the documentation on [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy/) and [Axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/) but I still can't seem to get it working. Maybe I am missing something..

My Vue component calling the **vuex action**:

```js
methods: {
  open() {
    this.$store.dispatch('events/getEventAlbum');
  }
}
```

The **action** in **vuex**:

```js
export const actions = {
  async getEventAlbum(store) {
    console.log('album action');
    const response = await Axios.get(url + '/photos?&sign=' +   isSigned + '&photo-host=' + photoHost);
    store.commit('storeEventAlbum', response.data.results);
  }
};
```

And my **nuxt.js.config**

```js
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
  '@nuxtjs/proxy'
],

axios: {
  proxy: true
},

proxy: {
  '/api/': {
    target: 'https://api.example.com/',
    pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' }
  }
}
```

Anybody who can help?

Comment: It will be your api blocking the request. What is the cors error you get in the console? What type of api are you using?

Comment: Hi @Andrew1325 , it's a **RESTful** API and I am getting the **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header** error.

Comment: Is your api an express (node.js) api?

Comment: @Andrew1325 , yes, Nuxt.js is built on top of Node & Express

Comment: @Manu No, Nuxt is built on top of Vue.js and apparently Node. Express is just an integration.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe the issue that @andrew1325 is trying to point out is that the **API provider** needs to have the CORS enabled, not just your server, without changing the headers in your proxy, you're passing the same headers, which at the moment prevent access.

It seems to me that you're only missing `changeOrigin`

please try the following config:

```js
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
  '@nuxtjs/proxy'
],

axios: {
  proxy: true
},

proxy: {
  '/api/': { target: 'https://api.example.com/', pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''}, changeOrigin: true }
}
```

also make sure that your front-end API url is pointing to your proxied request `/api`

Comment: Hi Daniel, **changeOrigin** did not make much of a difference. Still getting the same error.. ```Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/2/photos?&sign=true&photo-host=public&event_id=testID' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.```

Comment: then you're not hitting the proxy at all, so it doesn't matter what you set up through your config, because you're bypassing it completely. Can you show the code for `url`  (`const response = await Axios.get(url + ...`)? You probably just need to make that `/api`

Comment: It works fine if I paste the link ```https://api.example.com/2/photos?&sign=true&photo-host=public&event_id=testID``` in my browser so I am pretty sure it's nothing wrong with anything in my ```Axios.get()```

Comment: It's the browsers' security policy if you paste it in as a link, CORS is not an issue. you need to use `https://api.example.com/2/` as your **proxy target** and use `/api` **within your app**. That's what the proxy is for, it routes the traffic through a server rather than the browser getting it.

Comment: Is this possible to have this working on a Netlify static site?

Comment: @FirzokNadeem I don't think so. This is for development purposes only.

Comment: @FirzokNadeem no, because Netlify does not provide a running Node.js server (as of today). And it's not a good solution for production anyway.

Comment: Even if the accepted answer works, keep in mind that it's more of a band aid than an actual solution. For a real answer, please check [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585). TLDR being that you should ask the backend team to enable it or to whitelist your localhost into an admin dashboard. This will bring the great benefit of not having to rely on SSR (if your project could run on SSG without the proxy module).