# Need to modify the URL inside a onClick function while invoking fetch in reactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to reactJS. 
The below snippet is to invoke a URL on a click event.
But the URL fired is with the baseURI.

How can i truncate that or reset it ?

```
handleClick = (event) => {

 console.log("Got the row " + event );

 alert('The link was clicked.'+ event);
    fetch("www.google.com")
    .then(res => {
      console.log("Got the result "+   res.json());
    }
  );

};
```

The URL fired is

Response:

```
 {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/www.google.com", redirected: false, 
   status: 200, ok: true, …}
   (...)

  statusText: "OK"
  type: "basic"
  url: "http://localhost:3000/www.google.com"
```

I need to fire multiple calls within this handleClick event and then open a new tab if successful with the final URL along with the session key. The above code is just the beginning to check the calls work fine or not.

How should i truncate "http://localhost:3000" ??

Comment: Pass in complete url inside fetch for example `fetch("https://www.google.com")`.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch API doesn't know that it's an external link. Add the protocol to your url, i.e. `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: leads to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522749/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow

Comment: just pass the fetch options: to allow cros

Answer (score 0):

Fetching API from external link, you need to add complete URL like

> http://google.com

or

> https://google.com

Comment: its giving exception in chrome 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522749/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development @ShaikMd

Answer (score 0):

just pass the fetch options:

```js
fetch(URL, {
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
  }
})
```

Comment: check MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)