# Apache2 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header Despite proper tags

Tags: apache, cors

I'm having some issues with retrieving an RSS feed using jQuery on an apache2 localhost server. I am running Mac OS X Catalina. When I run this javascript:

```
$.get('url', function (data) {
    $(data).find("entry").each(function () { // or "item" or whatever suits your feed
        var el = $(this);

        console.log("------------------------");
        console.log("title      : " + el.find("title").text());
        console.log("author     : " + el.find("author").text());
        console.log("description: " + el.find("description").text());
    });
});
```

Chrome gives me the following error log:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'url' from origin 'http://localhost' has
>   been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header
>   is present on the requested resource.

My `/apache2/users/*.conf` looks like this:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/*/Sites/"
<Directory "/Users/*/Sites/">
  Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews Indexes
  AllowOverride All
  MultiviewsMatch Any
  Require all granted

  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  Header add Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Directory>
```

I also made sure mod_headers was installed and restarted apache:

```
$ httpd -M |grep header
$ sudo apachectl restart
```

I am still thrown the same error. I've read through all the posts I could find and still haven't found a solution. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: The error is just reported as (failed) by Chrome in the Network pane. I'm not given a specific code. Def not a 200 response though, as all other successful connections are listed as such

Comment: What happens if you try to open http://localhost/ directly in your browser?

Comment: @sideshowbarker That's what I've been doing - it brings up all files in my Sites directory.

Answer (score -1):

After some more research I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522749/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow) answer which recommends using [Moesif's Orign & CORS Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-orign-cors-changer/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc). With this addon, I was able to get a response from the feed.