# How can use payment getway in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel

I just made an `api` with Laravel, and front with ReactJS, but I'm wondering how can I use payment getway in this project, I want to use this [getway](https://github.com/RTLer/zarinpal-composer-library)

What I tried:

```
$zarinpal = new Zarinpal('XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX');
$zarinpal->isZarinGate(); // active zarinGate mode
$results = $zarinpal->request(
    "example.com/testVerify.php",
    1000,
    'testing',
    'me@example.com',
    '09000000000',
);

if (isset($results['Authority'])) {
    file_put_contents('Authority', $results['Authority']);
    $zarinpal->redirect();
}
```

It successfully get `$results['Authority'])` but it won't redirect to getway, clearly because I am using laravel as api, right? so how can I do this while I using api?

It give me this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/deposit/agent'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.
>
> POST http://localhost:8000/api/deposit/agent net::ERR_FAILED

But I don't have CORS issue on api request, it just give me this error on this action

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve 'Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522749/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow)