# I am using React in frontend and Spring Boot in back end, and I'm getting an error

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

This is code on Spring Boot side:

```
class FruitWrapper{

    List<String> fruits;
  }
class HelloController {
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String hello(@RequestBody FruitWrapper fruits)
     {
        System.out.println(fruits);
    
       return "he";
     }

    }
```

I am sending request from react like this:

```
 axios.post(`${COURSE_API_URL}`,{"fruits":["apple","orange"]})
.then(resp{console.log(resp.data)})
```

Error:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000'         has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Comment: check this out; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522749/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its happening due to CORS origin policy. You need to enable CORS in your server side. To set the origins for RESTful web service by using @CrossOrigin annotation for the controller method. This @CrossOrigin annotation supports specific REST API, and not for the entire application.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")

public ResponseEntity<Object> getProduct() {
   return null;
}
```

Global CORS Configuration

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
   return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
         registry.addMapping("/products").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9000");
      }    
   };
}
```

source: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_cors_support.htm