# Problem with ssr Cors then axios and proxy [SOLVED]

Tags: vue.js, axios, proxy, nuxt.js, http-status-code-504

I had problems yesterday that I never had on previous nuxt projects about CORS.

I have indeed read that it was necessary to set the proxy to solve the problem. Despite this, I have a 504 error. I followed several solutions found on the github repository & stack overflow without having found the problem.

My post function

```
await this.$axios.post("/api/contact", {
replyTo: this.form.email,
name: this.form.name,
firstName: this.form.firstName,
phone: this.form.phone,
company: "",
message: this.form.message,}).then(() => {this.isSend = true;}).catch((e) => {console.log(e);this.isError = true;});
```

my nuxt config

```
modules: ["@nuxtjs/axios", "@nuxtjs/proxy"],
axios: {
    proxy: true,
    debug: true,
},
proxy: {
    "/api/": {
        target: "http://myserver.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com/",
        pathRewrite: { "^/api/": "" },
        changeOrigin: true,
    },
},
```

my api call need to be done on http://myserver.eu-west-3.elasticbeanstalk.com/contact

I'm pretty sure I made a mistake somewhere, but I really can't find where...
[error504](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t03vg.png)
[Initial cors error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU4eP.png)

EDIT 1 : everything work find with postman, but not with my frontend i tried with a apigateway lambda ses, it's work with postman, not with front end, i tried with a node express server with ses, it's work with lambda, not with front end :(

EDIT 2 : I managed to make the form submission work, I cloned one of my old projects, then I replaced the content with that of this project. I think it's a nuxtJs and Axios problem. Very strange.

Comment: It's not confirmed that cors and 504 are related.

Comment: Try that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585

Comment: Sure, i edited and add the error that i got first with a more simple configuration that work for me earlier in every projects ;) https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU4eP.png

Comment: I already tried this @kissu :/ everything work find with postman, but not with my frontend

Comment: This is pretty much what I have written there (Postman doesn't have CORS). So, if it's working with Postman, it is still not fine.

Comment: I understand better, thank you. My server has the cors package configured and allows all origins. I don't understand why nuxt is blocking requests. It seems that pre-flight requests are responsible...