# After several attempts to overcome the CORS issue. no solution up to know, any suggestions please

Tags: node.js, server, vuejs3

After several attempts to overcome the CORS issue in vuejs axios. no solution up to know, any suggestions please

1. Create vue.config.js file

````
    devServer: {
        proxy: 'http://alantin.gr'
    },
  }; ``` 

2. Create webpack.config.js
````

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    devServer: {
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization"
        }
      }
  };
```

3. Add several plugins but didn't work or for security reasons was being disabled
4. Here is my app.vue file with the source code with in it

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{data}}
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  beforeMount(){
    this.getName();
  },
  methods: {
    async getName(){
      const res = await fetch('http://alantin.gr/users/');
      const data = await res.json();
      this.data = data;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Also the vue.config.js file exist on the root directory of the project
[folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYBmO.png)

last the package.json context

```
{
  "name": "aflix",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/cli": "^5.0.8",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.9",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.9",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.19",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I recommend this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585

Answer (score 0):

To overpass cors i use this tricky solution:
create a file `launch.json` inside `.vscode` folder.
Paste and copy this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--disable-web-security",
        ],
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    ]
  }
```

this configuration file set chrome with argument line: `--disable-web-security`, so in this chrome, cors will be disabled.

Than use vscode debug to launch custom chrome and you are done.

Remember to be careful while doing this, because as known cors purpose is to prevent malicious http redirect, if disable you are vulnerable to anything in the web.

Comment: On top of what, this will still not work on production.

Comment: Great it did work, but this is temporarly solution and I need to find another way to solve the issue without the vulnerabilities. Again thanks for your anwser

Comment: Yes, this is for development only