# Vue doesn't fetch data from API in first render

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-router

After logging in I call `await router.push('/');` to redirect to the home page where I load users and I get this error `GET http://localhost:8080/users 401` then when I  refrehs the page in the exact same component I get the data just fine with a `200 status`. I'm not sure what's going on

```js
async login (username, password) {

    const response = await axios.post('/auth/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
    });

    this.user = response.data;
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));

    await router.push('/');
},
```

This is the function I call after logging in

This is the `router.js`

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
import Login from '../views/Auth/Login.vue';
import { useAuthStore } from '../stores/auth.store.js';
import IndexUser from "../views/Users/IndexUser.vue";
import IndexHive from '../views/Hives/IndexHive.vue';

const routes = [
    { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: IndexUser },
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login },
    { path: '/users', redirect: { name: 'Home' } },
    { path: '/users/create', name: 'CreateUser', component: CreateUser },
    { path: '/hives', name: 'IndexHive', component: IndexHive }

];

import CreateUser from '../views/Users/CreateUser.vue';

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes
});

router.beforeEach(to => {

    const authStore = useAuthStore();

    const publicPages = ['/login'];
    const authRequired = !publicPages.includes(to.path);

    if (authRequired && !authStore.user) {
        return '/login';
    }
})

export default router;
```

This is the component I redirect to after logging in

```js
onMounted( async () => {
  const response = await axios.get('/users');
  users.value = response.data;
})
```

Devtools

[image]

Network tab

[image]

Axios Error

[image]

details of request/response

[image]

[image]

Response of login

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you check your network tab (browser devtools), you'll see that your 401 error is related to CORS. If so, check a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585).

Comment: @kissu but when I refresh the page I get the data after getting that error. And I already enabled the cors for the client in my backend

Comment: What do you see in your devtools alongside the error? For me, it's a CORS issue because you don't have it initially (while having a running server), then it happens because you're doing client-side navigation. Does it happen if you come back to the page with a client-side navigation (probably is).

Comment: I just saved a new user like `await axios.post('/users', user);`
 `await router.push('/');` to return back to the component and the results show just fine

Comment: @kissu I updated my question and added the devtools error

Comment: What do you have in your network tab? There may be more details there. Also, what is inside of the Axios error message object? May give more details. Anyway, [a 401](https://http.cat/401) is unauthorized so you're missing something in your credentials/rights I guess.

Comment: @kissu I updated my answer but why when I reload the page I don't get the error? This doesn't make sense to me

Comment: What if you click on `users` in the network tab, no more details? Do you have the same issue if you try with Postman/Insomnia? Do you have a public github repo?

Comment: @kissu I updated my answer and commit the project to github https://github.com/boumediane1/demo-vue

Comment: @kissu postman and insomnia work just fine

Comment: Got any public test credentials to share?

Comment: But the server is running in my local machine

Comment: Oh, won't be able to help further haha. As for the network tab, I was referring to preview/response. If it works with Postman, then it may be a CORS issue still. What do you have on backend's logs? The 401's reason should be logged there.

Comment: @kissu I attached the previous response again. All requests work fine with Postman. Thank you for your help anyway :)

Comment: the `/users` request is a get, which wouldn't send preflight. Also it returns a 401, so it seems indicative of the authentication being incorrect. If works on refresh, it seems indicative of a race condition.

Comment: @Daniel I tried a dummy api and it works but not in my api and it was working like a while ago. I'm not sure what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update 2

Having seen the code, I think the problem is here:

```js
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL;

if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user?.accessToken}`;
}
```

this will read the `axios.defaults.headers` when the `helpers/axios.js` file is loaded. This is why `axios.get('/users');` only works on second load, or rather only when the authentication is already loaded into localStorage. A change to the user object or a local storage will not update since this code only runs once at the beginning, the change to `axios.defaults.headers` needs to be dynamic.

#### Update

if `setTimeout` didn't work that could be due to a different issue. Also, if your request works a second time, but it also works if the authentication is passed directly, it seems to me that it has something to do with the authentication being handled implicitly.

I think what's happening is that you are creating multiple instances of axios and relying on shared authentication

```js
// create single axios instance
export const api = axios.create({
   withCredentials: true,
   baseURL: BASE_URL // optional
})

// then use
await api.post('/auth/login', {
  username: username,
  password: password
});

// and 
await api.get('/users');
```

This might make the axios instance remember the authentication information between calls. It may still require handling race condition if you have an app that doesn't wait on the `login` request to finish.

---

I think this is just an issue with a race condition

`POST:/login` and `GET:/users` requests appear to be done in parallel.

```js
onMounted( async () => {
  // this should wait until the `login` has been handled
  const response = await axios.get('/users');
  users.value = response.data;
})
```

I don't see how you call login so can't offer the the exact solution, but if you can store the `login` request state as a reactive variable, you can do something like

```js
watch: {
  loginState:{
    immediate: true
    handler(value){
      if (value === LOADED) {
        const response = await axios.get('/users');
        users.value = response.data;
      }
    }
  }
})
```

here's what the changes to the authStore might look like

```js
export const STATES = {
  INIT:"INIT",
  PROCESSING:"PROCESSING",
  ERROR:"ERROR",
  LOADED:"LOADED",
}
export const loginState = ref(STATES.INIT);

async login (username, password) {
    loginState.value = STATES.PROCESSING
    try{
      const response = await axios.post('/auth/login', {
        username: username,
        password: password
      });
      loginState.value = STATES.LOADED
      this.user = response.data;
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));

      await router.push('/');
    }catch(e){
      // handle error
      loginState.value = STATES.ERROR
    }
},
```

Comment: But how should it wait? I tried to set a timeout but not working

Comment: one approach is to use `watch` instead of `onMounted`, updated answer with options API example

Comment: My login is in another file `auth.store.js` here's the public github repo

Comment: I recommend validating first if that's the case. To do that, you could add a `setTimeout` before making the `users` request. If it works then my assertion is likely correct and then you can figure out how to solve for that. If not, then the issue may be something else. But it's important to validate first before you start looking into implementing a fix. Fixing the problem, however may fall out of the scope of the question

Comment: I found a hard time translating your code to the composition API but I tried the setTimeout like ```onMounted( async () => {
  setTimeout(() => {}, 5000);
  const response = await axios.get('/users');
  users.value = response.data;
})``` but still getting the error

Comment: your setTimeout is non-blocking and its use has no effect. you should have the code inside the function `setTimeout(async () => {***CODE GOES HERE***}, 5000)`

Comment: sorry for the delay. I tried it but it waits 5 seconds and the result is the same. The error still occurs

Comment: I passed the header along with the request ```await axios.get('/users', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${authStore.user.accessToken}`
    }
  });``` and it's working kinda dirty but it'll do for now

Comment: interesting. does the API use cookies? The code doesn't show how you handle the authentication token.

Comment: sorry for the delay. Here's how I handled the authentication when I first submitted this question. https://github.com/boumediane1/demo-vue/blob/main/src/helpers/axios.js (I'm using JWT) then I sent the Authentication header along with each request but it was bad practice then I did this instead

Comment: ```import axios from "axios";
import {useAuthStore} from "../stores/auth.store.js";

axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL;


axios.interceptors.request.use(
    config => {
        const authStore = useAuthStore();
        if (authStore.user) {
            config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${authStore.user.accessToken}`;
        }
        return config;
    }
)```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I learned a lot from your answer

Comment: I had a look at the code and see what caused this behaviour, have a look at the updated answer

Comment: Thanks Dan. You explained it very well