# Error on my nuxt app TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'meta.token'

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building a login page and to pass the token from the backend I modify my nuxt config file with this strategy:

```js
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'meta.token' },
          logout: { url: '/auth/logout', method: 'post' },
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

my login page:

```html
  <div>
    <div>
      <form action="#" @submit.prevent="login">
        <b-form-input
          v-model="form.name"
          id="input-default"
          placeholder="Enter Username"
          type="text"
        ></b-form-input>
        <b-form-input
          v-model="form.password"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          type="password"
        ></b-form-input>
   
        <b-button type="submit" variant="success">Login</b-button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      
      form: {
        name: "",
        password: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods:  { 
  async  login() {
        try {
            await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
              data: this.form,
            });
         this.$router.push({path : "index"});
        } catch (error) {
            this.messageError = error
        }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Server-side I've added a custom response that returns login data in this way

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "",
    "code": 200,
    "data": {
        "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjgwMDAvYXBpL2F1dGgvbG9naW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2NzExMzA2NDUsImV4cCI6MTY3MTEzNDI0NSwibmJmIjoxNjcxMTMwNjQ1LCJqdGkiOiJQcXc1bHNmY1JWN2dLdVZUIiwic3ViIjoiMyIsInBydiI6IjIzYmQ1Yzg5NDlmNjAwYWRiMzllNzAxYzQwMDg3MmRiN2E1OTc2ZjcifQ.0IB-Efk3RaZY4NzHRIQS0CmH95KKa4-vF3dNJG2fNBg"
    }
}
```

I receive the error

> TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'meta.token'

Comment: Which version of Node and Nuxt? Using Vite or Webpack?

Comment: @kissu I'm using laravel 9 and nuxt 2.15.8 and vite

Comment: Nuxt 2 and Vite? Sure about it?

Comment: nuxt 2 yes I verified on package.json file, Vite no, I'm not sure

Comment: @kissu so any solutions?

Comment: Do you properly receive a `meta.token` in your network tab?

Comment: Okay It was just a proxy problem.. but now i receive a cors policy problem: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: This is the way to go for CORS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585

Answer (score 0):

OP solved that one by fixing a proxy issue. Was probably a typo or something similar.