# Integrate Nuxt3 js as frontend in Ruby on Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, configuration, nuxtjs3

I have a Rails(7.0) project and Nuxt3 as Front End. Both are separately working fine.

what I want is to use Nuxt pages as view when I hit Rails routes.

Unfortunately, i found only those projects/examples where Rails & Nuxt3 are separately running.

examples:
https://medium.com/@fishpercolator/how-to-separate-frontend-backend-with-rails-api-nuxt-js-and-devise-jwt-cf7dd9da9d16

https://github.com/KevinBerthier/nuxt-rails-a-la-webpacker

So how I can render Nuxt3 pages from Rails controller.

Comment: Look for a gem that handles Vite and Nuxt, skip webpack. Not sure why you would want Nuxt on top of Rails tho, looks like a duplicate to have SSR twice. Rails + Vue is probably a more common pattern overall. But yeah, expect to not have an easy time setting this one up since this is not the common way of doing things (usually you do split both the backend and front-end).

Comment: ok, i got your point and you are completely right!
I've created a Nuxt3 app and I want to call 3rd party APIs with private tokens, save API responses in the cache, and use cached data in Pages.

but facing CORS issue also unable to use redis

Comment: CORS is mostly backend thing to fix, more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585

Answer (score 2):

I made a similar project with a Rails backend and Nuxt frontend. My Nuxt app was configured to `ssr: false, target: 'static'` and I would export it as a static site, and copy over the generated files to Rails' public folder, so that I can serve the `index.html` via rails routes. This is just when doing deployment, though. During development, I just run 2 separate servers (Rails and Nuxt) on different ports.

I just added `get '*unmatched_route', :to => 'application#index'` at the end of `routes.rb` to catch any route and basically pass it to nuxt and let it handle the rendering. I also added this in `application_controller.rb`:

```
def index
  render file: Rails.root.join('public/index.html'), layout: false
end
```

I can then add routes in `routes.rb` (before the wildcard) for the APIs I would like to call via nuxt. Since both the Nuxt app (static HTML) and the Rails API are served by the same rails server, I don't run into the CORS issue when the Nuxt app calls the Rails API.

The only downside with this approach is that you can't preload data in the nuxt app as it is served (aka SSR). You can only serve the static nuxt app and let it get data via XHR requests to the Rails API.