# Nuxt 3 useFetch Authorization

Tags: authorization, nuxt3, usefetch

When sending the Authorization header I get a 401 error. When checking in postman, an error occurred

useFetch code:

```
await useFetch(`${config.public.baseUrl}/bus_stops`, {
        method: 'GET',
        watch: false,
        headers: {
            authorization: `Bearer ${authToken.value}`,
        },
        params: params,
        onResponse({response}) {
            busStops.value = [];
            // @ts-ignore
            busStops.value = response._data.data;
            isLoading.value = true;
        },
    });
```

I send an authorization token and expect a 200 response but get a 401

Comment: "When checking in postman, an error occurred", the issue is not on Nuxt's side then. But on the server you're trying to login to. A typo or some other tiny mistake.

Comment: postman: response 200
nuxt app: response 401

Comment: Double-check your browser devtools, network tab to see exactly what you're sending. There is maybe a typo or `authToken` is maybe wrongly imported etc...

Comment: copy from devtools:
Authorization: Bearer 18|kgaBvdhgk8p1bqFYrc7pXoP72wfWRdCB3sE2VmqKcd64a7cc

copy from postman:
Authorization: Bearer 18|kgaBvdhgk8p1bqFYrc7pXoP72wfWRdCB3sE2VmqKcd64a7cc

the lines are similar

Comment: Check the rest of the query, not only the token.

Comment: everything is identical. 

Errors "Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers" started appearing in the console

Comment: Here we go, that's the interesting error. Regular CORS issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585