# Mercedes API Has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I try to get data with Mercedes API, but I have CORS policy problem.
I use Vue js, my website is hosted on firebase.

API Docs : https://developer.mercedes-benz.com/products/vehicle_specification/docs#

```
async function getVehicleSpecifications() {
  const apiKey = 'MY API KEY'; // Hidden for the screenshoot
  const locale = 'fr_FR';
  const url = `https://api.mercedes-benz.com/vehicle_specifications/v1/vehicles/${vin.value}?locale=${locale}`;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'x-api-key': apiKey,
        'accept': 'application/json',
      },
    });

    vehicleSpecifications.value = response.data;
    console.log(response.data); 
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur réseau ou de serveur :', error);
  }
}
```

[screenshot of the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cKoR.png)

Comment: If you have to use an API key, it usually means, you shouldn't access the API with a browser. Are you aware that all users can see the API key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522749/how-to-solve-redirect-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow?rq=2