Firebase Auth for Nuxt Website not working on mobile devices
I built a website with Nuxt and used Firebase Auth for Authentication.
After deploying it I thought everything worked well, until i tested it on my mobile devices.
On Smartphones and Tables (tested on IOS, Android and IpadOS with multiple Browsers) it is not working.
When i want to log in, i always get redirected to my Login Screen. The Log in the google cloud is looking good and no error appears. 
In the browser console on the devices (e.g. chrome://inspect) i couldn't find any errors either.
If you want to test it by yourself, here is the repository:
https://github.com/julix14/attraction_stack
And here is the live app:
https://activityapp-419511.web.app/
I don't have a real clue if there are any other options to debug on mobile, or any way to have a more comprehensive console with better loggings. And it would be good to know if somebody has a hint from which direction the error can come, because in my understanding i thought that a website works the same way on all devices and browsers...
If you need further information, please let me know what i should provide.
EDIT:
I managed to look at the log of my iphone and it says the followig:
Blocked https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise/pat?k=<KEY> from asking for credentials because it is a cross-origin request.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()

As proposed in your previous question, you can debug remotely on your Android phone: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging Maybe also a way of doing it on an iPhone I think, I've never tried.

I added the log message to the question @kissu

Oh? Weird but look for CORS and how to solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585 Are you sure you set it properly? CORS should not be a thing for captcha... But that would explain the 401.
