NuxtJs - Fetch API blocked by CORS
I'm using Nuxt 3, and i'm facing problem with CORS, as follows:

Access to fetch at 'https://server_api_url:port/refinement/login' from origin
'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

But it works when I test with Postman, I also tried deploying to a domain name, I wonder if this error originates from my frontend or the server side?
This is my config API call:
    import { StatusCode, type JSONResponse } from "~/misc/types";
    export const useApiFetch = () => {
        const config = useRuntimeConfig();
        const token = useCookie("token")
    
        const customFetch = async (url: string, options = {}) => {
            try {
                // Set default headers
                options.headers = {
                    ...options.headers,
                    Authorization: token.value,
                    Device: Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999).toString(),
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": '*',
                };
                // Perform the fetch request
                const response: any = await $fetch(url, {
                    baseURL: config.public.apiBase,
                    ...options
                });
                // Assuming the data you need is in the `data` property
                return response;
            } catch (error: any) {
                if (error?.response?.status === StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZE) {
                    navigateTo("/login")
                }
                let obj = {
                    data: error?.response || error,
                    status_code: error?.response?.status || 500
                }
                // Customize the error message or structure here
                return obj as JSONResponse
            }
        };
    
        return customFetch;
    };


Please use a quick search before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585

Thanks for your nonsensical answer to me

Not sure what is not clear in my other answer: you have the why it works in Postman and the how to fix it. Please read the answer first. "I wonder if this error originates from my frontend or the server side?", as written in my answer, it is a backend/backoffice issue here.

@aprogramer Contrary to what you seem to believe, CORS is to be configured on the server side, not on the client side; you can safely drop those Access-Control-... headers from your request, as those are response headers. Have you attempted to configure your server for CORS?
