Nuxt 3 + Directus returns CORS error when navigating the site
I have searched, and searched, and searched... for an answer to this problem. I just can't figure out the solution.
The problem I'm having concerns a project with Nuxt 3 as frontend, and Directus (CMS) as backend (running in a Docker container):
When I enter the site normally, as in, for example -- I update the site (with F5) -- then the data is retrieved (with @directus/sdk) completely fine. The data can be displayed (and is retrieved as expected).
But as soon as I try to navigate between pages (using <NuxtLink>), I can't even enter the site/route, and the console prints the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
the remote resource at http://localhost:8055/items/pages/about.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status
code: 200.

As well as with this error message:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
the remote resource at http://localhost:8055/items/index. (Reason:
CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

But as said, the error ONLY shows up when I'm trying to navigate using links on the page.
I have uploaded a sample project to my Github. (Of course, this could be a problem/issue that only I'm facing): https://github.com/fexell/nuxt-directus-test
I thank you in beforehand, and hope someone out there has a solution to this problem! :)

The initial render comes from the server, hence no CORS issues. Here's an example and how to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72211930/8816585 TLDR: it's not on the frontend that you'll be able to fix this.
