# m3u8 video cros domain error in angular 4

Tags: angular, stream, video.js, http-live-streaming

I use videojs in angular 4 project for play m3u8 streams . Many of this streams get Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

like : http://5.202.183.253:8080/live/irib1.m3u8

They work in mobile app and Chrome play hls extension

Comment: nobody can help ?

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this'll help you yet, but when you use some service provider like AWS S3, you need to set CORS permissions on the provider. Check the documentation to confirm if all was already set to you.