# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values

Tags: angularjs, cors, ionic3

I have developed the Woocommerce ionic app but when i connect the app with live site or server then its gives this **error** :

```
Access to fetch at 'https://www.example.co.uk/shop/wp-json/v3/products/categories?filter[meta]=true&filter[variation]=true' 
    from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight
     request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains
     multiple values 'http://localhost:8100, *', but only one is allowed. Have the server send the 
    header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Please see the below screenshots as well : 
[image]

**To resolve this error i have also paste the below code on my server .htaccess file** :

```
Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "HEAD, POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE"
Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Accept-Charset,X-Accept,Content-Type,Credentials"
```

But still it showing the same error.

Before 1 months its working fine.
I am using **ionic CLI version is : 3.4.0** and **npm version is : 6.6.0**

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message the browser receives the following response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8100, *
```

Specifying multiple origins in the response is not allowed and thus you get CORS error.

You should try to understand what makes your server return multiple values.
I would:

1. Try with incognito without any extensions as some extensions could
   modify this header.
2. Search in the code and Apache config files for
   any line with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: I have check by disable all the browser extension but still it showing the same error.

Comment: This error start when our site change from http to https.

Comment: It could be that you have some CORS config which applies only for https

Answer (score 0):

This issue mainly occurred from server side 
try to change you .htaccess file

Like

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Refer ans from
[htaccess Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421463/htaccess-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have already set this Header  set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in .htaccess file on server. But still it not working, Only shows loading... Banner.

Comment: Please Check your config.xml file does it has this line else add it
    <access origin="*" />

Comment: There in no any file with name config.xml , I am using Wordpress and have .htaccess file . Also i have added the above code but still not working.