# Enabled Cross Origin Resource Sharing in .htaccess does not work

Tags: cors

I created a .htaccess file on my image server (maptile.org).

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

I enabled mod-headers using `a2enmod headers`
I tested that it was enabled with `apachectl -M` and it listed  `headers_module (shared)`

This was recommended in the question: 
[Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin in .htaccess doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640596/header-set-access-control-allow-origin-in-htaccess-doesnt-work)

However when I try to save a map as an image (using html2canvas) it gives me an error in the console
http://www.justicemap.org/?id=63

The error:

> Image from origin 'http://maptile.org' has been blocked from loading
>   by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://www.justicemap.org' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

The Save as Image function works when the images are stored on the justicemap.org domain.

When I use html2canvas the request method is "GET", the response status code is "200", and the mimeType is "image/png".  I do not see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Do I need to add an Origin header?  I don't see one when I examine the requests in the Chrome Javascript console.

Comment: I'm using Cloudflare for DNS.  Could that affect this?    This link says that Cloudflare supports CORS: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200308847-Does-CloudFlare-support-Cross-origin-resource-sharing-CORS-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't running Apache. I was using Lighttpd.  I didn't realize this because Cloudflare replaced the server header with: `Server:cloudflare-nginx`.

I was able to configure Lighttpd to work using [this recommendation](http://www.gubatron.com/blog/2011/11/29/lighttpd-allow-access-control-allow-origin-headers-on-the-server-status-page/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved by setting the `crossOrigin` option to `null`, like this:

```
layers: [
  new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM({
      url: 'http://tile-server-ip/osm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      crossOrigin: null
    })
  })
],
```