# handling CORS preflight request in Apache

Tags: apache, http-headers

I have a AngularJS app deployed using Yeoman. Cakephp RESTful backend.

The Angular app sends in OPTIONS preflight requests, which the backend responds with forbidden (403), in nginx to solve this problem I have used this:

```
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'; 
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE'; 
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-AuthTokenHeader,Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';   
     add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
     add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
     add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
     return 204; 
}
```

How do I go about doing this in Apache? Please provide some preliminary guidance/comments, I will figure out the details after that and improve the question with granular details.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same question and the answer given does not solve the problem.

By looking around more I found you could do this using the rewrite, e.g:

```
RewriteEngine On                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

(make sure you enable the rewrite mod)

Then you should use, the "always set" to set the headers, e.g:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"                   
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
```

Explanations here: https://serverfault.com/questions/231766/returning-200-ok-in-apache-on-http-options-requests

Comment: You saved me after 2 bad days!

Comment: You saved a life today, the only solution that works after 2 days and trying basically all the things possible

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your .htaccess file to your apache root directory:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Make sure to activate the apache module headers:

```
a2enmod headers
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11691776/1494875

Answer (score 3):

If it helps -
I was using authentication so I also had to add following to make POST request work for me:

```
<LimitExcept OPTIONS>
  Require valid-user 
</LimitExcept>
```