# External form isset equals false and returns no input value

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I've created a simple form located on another website(server).

When  the form on www.b.com is submitted using the www.a.com/best-rate.php action I'm getting no return values from the input.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the input information from server to server. For some reason when I run this I get

> false

which indicates that it is not set. Am I over thinking this? Should this not return the value or should I do something different?

## www.a.com/best-rate.php

```
include "db_conx.php";
if (isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        echo 'true';
    }
    else 
        echo 'false';
```

The form is located below and on website B. Again, this is on another website and server all together. We'll call it www.b.com

## www.b.com (Where the form is located)

```
<form action="https://www.a.com/best-rate.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

## UPDATE

When using the **get** method I'm able to receive the form inputs, but **post** seems to not want to accept them. In the future, sensitive information could be passed so I want to stick with post.

UPDATE .htaccess

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: Try using `var_dump($_POST)` to see if anything is passed to your page.

Comment: @VladBardalez thanks for the reply.

`array(0) {
}
`

That is the return value.

Comment: Knowing that the array is empty can it be determined that their is a different approach to running accepting inputs for an external script like this?

Comment: Changed the method to "GET" and was able to return a value, but would rather use "POST" as some information may be sensitive in the future. Is this adding any clarity as to why this method will not work server to server using "POST"?

Comment: It seems like post method in your server environment is subject to same origin policy. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640596/header-set-access-control-allow-origin-in-htaccess-doesnt-work

Comment: @TomaszCz. I took a look and after inputting the .htaccess to the directory where the script is located I had no results. No errors or results. I listed what was added above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the session using

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
session_start();
```

before you can read the values.  This also has to be done before you emit any http headers

Comment: The form is located on a page that doesn't allow PHP. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: On the best-rate.php form (it looks like a php form) you need to execute session start before you can look at the session values.