# Can't retrieve user information from the server by using axios (Get) Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to retrieve the user information (like email, DoB, ... etc.) and in the component I did this:

```
 const instance = axios.create({
            timeout: 1000,
            headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "APPLICATION_ID": "XXXXX",
            "CLIENT_KEY": "XXXXX",
            "token": "Token"
            }
        });
        instance.get("url/" + app.id)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log("I am here!");
            app.phone = response.data.result._User.phone;
            app.email = response.data.result._User.email;
            app.dob = response.data.result._User.dob;
            app.website = response.data.result._User.website;
            app.country = response.data.result._User.ountry;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error!");
        });
```

but it is always providing this error message:

```
Failed to load https:url/XXXXXX: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

How can I fix this problem?

In addition, print in console `Error!`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32500073/request-header-field-access-control-allow-headers-is-not-allowed-by-itself-in-pr

Comment: You should allowed `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in headers

Comment: Read more about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: @Hearner where should I put it? I am a beginner so I am not professional in these things. help me :)

Comment: In `headers`, add a line `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"`

Comment: @Hearner where can I find the headers? Is it a file?

Comment: @ZahraaJawadJaber no, you already have it, `axios.create({
            timeout: 1000,
            headers: {` right after your timeout. Just add the line `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"`

Comment: @Hearner It is not work! error msg `Failed to load https://XXXXXX Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: Add `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'` before

Comment: @Hearner even when I add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" by itself, error msg is provided for me.

Comment: @Hearner Also, not work :( .. error msg : `Failed to load https:XXXXX Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Comment: This means that the server is not passing back in the header `access-control-allow-headers: token`.
If your server is an Apache with `. htaccess` you can add your header as the following:
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Token".

In this answer there is additional information on how to set up headers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640596/header-set-access-control-allow-origin-in-htaccess-doesnt-work