# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource - CORS issue

Tags: php, apache, cors, ubuntu-16.04

[image]

I get this error when using forms, like likebuttons, sending comments or opening a dialogue window.

I tried to put the CORS header into my apache2 config and htaccess file.

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` needs to be present in the response headers of the remote server. Looking at your URLs though, is the only difference that one has a `www.` prefix? If they're the same host, use a path instead of a full URI to make AJAX requests

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, try this on the top of your `.htaccess` file, hopefully it would work:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

If it did not, you might search on SE, there should be many similar posts about it such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640596/header-set-access-control-allow-origin-in-htaccess-doesnt-work).

Finally, if you could not solve it, you might try looking for solutions on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).