# php - sending 2 forms at once to two different pages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am sending two forms at the same time but there is an error in my script. I've researched the error - Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object # is not a function. They told me to add a submit button but there is a submit button already here is my form

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="page1.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="pt" id="pt" value="<?=$b64string?>" style="width:800px; padding: 10px;">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="page2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?=$_sign?>"/>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<span onclick="submitBoth();" style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="image1.png"></span>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
jQuery.post("form2.php", jQuery("#form2").serialize(), function(data){
    if(data.trim()=='valid'){
        document.form1.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: form elements need to be inside the form to be considered part of it. I've never tried this but try putting a hidden submit inside each form.

Comment: Use `$("#form1").trigger('submit');` instead of `document.form1.submit()`;

Comment: hi @RickCalder it didn't work i tried adding `<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>` form2 submits but form didn't i didn't get any error after.

Comment: hi @N.B. tried using yours to form1 did not submit. Also i did not get any errors.

Comment: i edited my title its supposed to be send it to two pages.

Comment: i got this working using the idea of @N.B. but i changed it by triggering the submit button `jQuery('#submit1').trigger('click');` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you use 'form2' as submission URL, is that correct?

`jQuery.post("form2", jQuery("#form2").serialize() ... etc`

first param of jqery.post needs to be an url.

Comment: sorry it was a typo i edited it before placing it here. Should be form2.php

Comment: so why dont just use smth like this?

`jQuery.post("form2.php", jQuery("#form2").serialize(), function(data){
   // you sure, that response will be a string, right?
    if(data.trim()=='valid'){
        jQuery.post("form1.php", jQuery("#form1").serialize(),        function(data){
     // todo: postprocess form1.php responce
    });
    }
});`

Comment: i've tried it awhile ago but the other server has restrictions and i think they don't accept ajax posts from other sites. i'm passing the forms to different pages and different hosts.

Comment: but thanks for the help also!

Comment: In case of cross-domain requests, the post below could be useful:

You should follow a different pattern. Your local JS will do an ajax post to a local URL which will accept the POST method with your json data.

At this point your server code will do an HTTP POST with proper data to the remote server, get the response, and send it back to the calling js.

see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761982/jquery-cross-domain-post-shenanigans

Answer (score 0):

so why dont just use smth like this?

```
jQuery.post("form2.php", jQuery("#form2").serialize(), function(data){
   // you sure, that response will be a string, right?
    if(data.trim()=='valid'){
        jQuery.post("form1.php", jQuery("#form1").serialize(), function(data){
     // todo: postprocess form1.php responce
    });
    }
});
```

and sorry for previous comment markup

Answer (score 0):

i got this working using the idea of N.B but i changed it by triggering the submit button `jQuery('#submit1').trigger('click');` thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
function submitBoth(){
    $.post('form1.php',$('form[name=form1]').serializeArray(),function(){
          $('form[name=form2]').submit();
    });
}
```