# Server Code HTTp POST to remote server; Javascript API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, http

I found an answer to a question that tells what to do, but I don't know how to implement it.

[jQuery cross domain POST shenanigans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761982/jquery-cross-domain-post-shenanigans)

I'm programming in Django and javascript

Steps:

> 1. ajax post to a local URL - How do I do this? Where do I post this to?
> 2. Server code will do an HTTP POST to remote server - How do I do this in django?
> 3. Send response to JS - I can figure that out.

Thanks

Comment: 1) You create your own URL that runs your server-side code. 2) https://www.google.com/search?q=dhango+http+post

Answer (score 1):

1. use the $ajax() function from jquery
2. use urllib and urllib2 to access external resources from python. Call these libraries from within your view function

Here's an example for the $ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/htmlApi/sendSms/',
    data: {
        'phone':'+12412354135',
        },
    success: function(data){
        $("#ajaxDestination").html(data);
    }
});
```

here's an example of a view function that posts data to the remote server:

```
def verify1(request):
    u = request.session['user']
    u.phone_number = request.GET['phone']
    u.save()


    apiUrl = "http://www.XXXXXXXXX.net/api/send.aspx?username=XXXXXXX&password=XXXXXX&language=1&sender=XXXXXX&mobile=" + request.GET['phone'] + "&message=" + 'ghis' + " is your verification code."
    x = urllib2.urlopen(apiUrl).read()


    return HttpResponse(x)
```

(This is an automated sms sending api call)

Comment: A few question: Does the function [def verify1] go in the specific view? for me it's postdate [postdata.html].

Comment: My api are originally curl commands, how do I call them? Can I still use urllib2?

Comment: I don't understand your first question, and I'm not sure what curl is. Sorry